# При добавлении SSL сертификата сайт не загружается до конца

Tags: ssl, https, хостинг

При добавлении SSL сертификата сайт не загружается до конца, причем без него все работает стабильно, а с ним при загрузке некоторых страниц у некоторых элементов выдает в консоль:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Заметил, что такую ошибку часто выдает на странице с каталогом, подгружаемым из БД у картинок. Сайт на хостинге eternalhost. Иногда сайт вообще не загружается. В общем я в недоумении. С телефона этот же каталог вообще не грузится, адрес каталога https://rentkap.ru/area.php. Также на телефоне не работают картинки даже на главной странице(а они там есть).[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, подробностей.

Comment: https://www.rentkap.ru/area.php вот страничка с основными проблемами , а также сайт не загружается на телефонах

Comment: У меня сейчас вообще ERR_TIMED_OUT. У вас есть доступ к логам сервера? Посмотрите что там происходит.

Comment: error log https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YPrwdxTWayKgyTvDHr1TI05t9hfSP0Ei/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Вставьте релевантные строки лога в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: еще есть access log

Comment: Пока что я вижу что у вас к nginx подключен и работает модуль ngx_http_limit_req_module: https://parg.co/8eV

Comment: И что с ним следует сделать?И в нем ли проблема?

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема была не в ssl. Проблема заключалась в параметре защита от DDOS атак , был выставлен слишком маленький лимит подключений. Всем спасибо!